# Square root of a 2 variable quadratic - integration (2 different results - principal square root and factoring)

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the integral and the result according to wolfram alpha

$$ \int_0^R \sqrt{r^2 + z^2 - 2zr}\;dr = \frac{r(r-2z)\sqrt{(r-z)^2}}{2(r-z)}\Bigg|_0^R \\
=\frac{R^2}{2} - zR
$$

where $z$ is a constant and $ 0 \leq z < R$

Now lets factor the expression under the square root

$$ \int_0^R \sqrt{(r - z)^2}  \; dr$$

The square root only returns a magnitude according to convention (because we want it to be a function). So we have $|r - z|$ and our integral becomes

$$ \int_0^z z - r \; dr + \int_z^R r - z \; dr \\ 
\text{or} \\
zr - \frac{r^2}{2}\Bigg|_0^z + \frac{r^2}{2} - zr\Bigg|_z^R \\
\frac{R^2}{2} - zR  + z^2
$$

Why do I get 2 different results? Is the first method wrong and if so why? I must be integrating different functions if I'm getting different results. The 2nd method is the area under 2 line segments. The 1st method is the area under the slice of the surface $w = \sqrt{r^2 + z^2 -2zr}$ where the slice is at some constant $z$. I'm confused what the math is saying in each situation. The 2 situations are different, but I don't know why they are different. It must somehow come down to the difference between $\sqrt{r^2 + z^2 - 2rz}$ and $|r - z|$. Aren't $\sqrt{(x-a)^2}$ and $|x-a|$ the same function? They can't be exactly the same because $\int_0^{10+a}\dots \; dx$, depending on the integrand, gives different results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function
$$ r \mapsto \frac{r(r-2z)\lvert r-z \rvert}{2 (r-z)} = \left(\frac{r^2}{2} - r z\right)\operatorname{sgn}(r-z) $$
is discontinuous at $r=z$ . It is a valid antiderivative of $r \mapsto \lvert r-z\rvert$ on the intervals $[0,z]$ and $[z,R]$ individually, but not on the whole interval $[0,R]$ , since it is of course not differentiable at $r=z$ as well.

If you split the interval of integration accordingly, you can still get the correct result:
$$ - \left(\frac{r^2}{2} - r z\right) \Bigg|_0^z + \left(\frac{r^2}{2} - r z\right) \Bigg|_z^R = \frac{R^2}{2} - z R +z^2 \, .$$